# Access external files as local files with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a source and several user domains. I'm keeping JS, CSS and image files on the source domain and in the user domains I'm including those stuffs like `source.com/js/jquery.js` but I want to show them like `user1.com/js/jquery.js`, `user2.com/js/jquery.js` without the files physically there.

```
source.com/css/bootstrap.css
source.com/js/jquery.js
source.com/user/1/library/picture.png
source.com/user/2/library/picture.png

user1.com/css/bootstrap.css
user1.com/js/jquery.js
user1.com/library/picture.png

user2.com/css/bootstrap.css
user2.com/js/jquery.js
user2.com/library/picture.png
```

Is this possible with htaccess? And for helping, all of these `source.com`, `user1.com`, `user2.com` are in the same server.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: For example in `user1.com .htaccess` use `RewriteRule ^js/jquery.js$ http://source.com/js/jquery.js [L]` .

Comment: @Damon.s When I go to the `user1.com/js/jquery.js` browser redirects me to the `source.com/js/jquery.js`. Is it possible without redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, test this :

in `user1.com`   `.htaccess` use `RewriteRule`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^js/jquery.js$ http://source.com/js/jquery.js [P]

</IfModule>
```

then your url is something like this `http://user1.com/js/jquery.js` and file will be read from `http://source.com/js/jquery.js` without changing url.

This worked for me.

Comment: Wow that's perfect. It works. So can we do this for all the files inside css, js directories? When I enter a filename `http://user1.com/js/*.js` it'll open the original one `http://source.com/js/*.js`.

Comment: @ozgrozer Yes, you can. example `RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ http://source.com/js/$1 [P]`

Comment: That's amazing. Thank you so much.